# How to get this parent value?

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get a value thanks to parents method of jQuery, but I can't find the good "way".

Can you help me please ?

The event is on the click of .user-create class, and the value to get is "09h00"

Now, I do it: `myVar = $(this).closest('div').prevAll(':last').children('.heure').text();` but it doesn't work

```
<li>
   <div class="docheure">
      <span class="heure">
         09h00 <!--IT'S THE VALUE I NEED -->
      </span>
      <span class="doc">
         Dr.Grey
      </span>
   </div>
   <div class="detailrdv">
      <p><span>M / Mme</span> : blabla | <span>Phone</span>: 00000</p>
      <p><span>Examen</span> : crane | <span>Secrétaire</span> : M.J</p>
      <p><span>Remarque :</span></p>
      <p>
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="contenercommandes">
      <div style="display: none;" class="commandes">
         <ul>
            <li>
               <!--THIS IS THE LINK EVENT-->
               <a href="#" class="editer">
                  <img src="btn_edit.png" alt="editer">
               </a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>

</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this should work:

```
myVar = $(this).closest('li:has("div.docheure")').find('.heure').text();
```

---

**Edited** in response to @lonesomeday's accurate comment. (I missed the nested `ul`/`li`)

Comment: Presuming we're starting at `a.editer`, `closest` will find the wrong `li`.

Comment: @lonesomeday: you're absolutely right. I can't believe I missed the nested `ul`/`li`...sigh. My eyes, they don't work any more... =/ (answer edited).

Comment: @bahamut100, no problem at all! ...it's probably worth thanking @lonesomeday too, though. If he hadn't caught my stupidity I'd've left the wrong answer up =/

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$(this)
 .closest('div.contenercommandes')
 .siblings('div.docheure')
 .find('span.heure')
 .text();
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/weNyN/).

Comment: THanks, it's works, but the answer of David Thomas works in more case

Comment: @bahamut100 You can upvote more than one answer, you know ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest('div').prevAll(':last').children('.heure').text();
```

instead you must use, html(). Like:

```
$('.docheure .heure').html()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("a.editer").click(function () {
    var myVal = $(this)
        .closest('.contenercommandes')
        .prevAll('.docheure')
        .children('.heure')
        .text()
    ;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of thing you were after? http://jsfiddle.net/thewebdes/ZQasw/

```
$('.user-create').click(function(){
  alert($('span.heure').html());
});
```

Comment: I assume that there are multiple "span.heure" tags in the document, which is why he needs the selector help.

Comment: @nickf Ok, yeah. The traversing method is the way to go then!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should help.

```
myVar = $(this).closest('div.docheure').find('.heure').text();
```

Comment: Judging by the number of simultaneous answers - all of them different - I'd guess that we've all interpreted the question differently ;-)

Comment: And @David Thomas navigated back to the .docheure div more accurately than me - kudos!